# Nginx redirect Http to Https - what's wrong here?

Tags: http, redirect, https, nginx

I have an Nginx server which should redirect all requests from http://www.domain.com and http://domain.com and https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com

So with or without www and with or without ssl I want the user to always get to https://www.domain.com.

After reading the nginx documentation and researching on google this is my current nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name .domain.com;
  return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen                       443 ssl;
  server_name                  .domain.com;
  ssl_certificate              /etc/ssl/private/[pem file];
  ssl_certificate_key          /etc/ssl/private/[key file];
  ssl_session_timeout          5m;
  ssl_protocols                SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers                  HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers    on;
  keepalive_timeout            70;
  ###
  ### Deny known crawlers.
  ###
  if ($is_crawler) {
    return 403;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass                 http://nginx_http;
    proxy_redirect             off;
    proxy_set_header           Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-By    $server_addr:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header           X-Local-Proxy     $scheme;
    proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass_header          Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header          Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header          X-Accel-Expires;
    proxy_pass_header          X-Accel-Redirect;
    proxy_pass_header          X-This-Proto;
    proxy_connect_timeout      300;
    proxy_send_timeout         300;
    proxy_read_timeout         300;
    proxy_buffer_size          4k;
    proxy_buffers              4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    access_log                 off;
    log_not_found              off;
  }
 50 }
```

What happens is that requests to http://domain.com get correctly redirected to https://www.domain.com but requests to http://www.domain.com are *not* being redirected (and the website is delivered without ssl).

UPDATE:

As this is part of a server set up by BOA (Barracuda Octopus Aegir) there are several config files in use. This is the nginx.conf which is loaded as well:

```
# Aegir web server main configuration file

#######################################################
###  nginx.conf main
#######################################################

 ## FastCGI params
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME         $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI         $request_uri;
  fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
  fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
  fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE     ApacheSolaris/$nginx_version;
  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;
  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT         $remote_port;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
  fastcgi_param  USER_DEVICE         $device;
  fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE  $geoip_country_code;
  fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;
  fastcgi_param  GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME  $geoip_country_name;
  fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;

 ## Default index files
  index         index.php index.html;

 ## Size Limits
  client_body_buffer_size        64k;
  client_header_buffer_size      32k;
  client_max_body_size          100m;
  large_client_header_buffers 32 32k;
  connection_pool_size           256;
  request_pool_size               4k;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size  512;
  server_names_hash_max_size    8192;
  types_hash_bucket_size         512;
  map_hash_bucket_size           192;
  fastcgi_buffer_size           128k;
  fastcgi_buffers             256 4k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size     256k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size  256k;

 ## Timeouts
  client_body_timeout             60;
  client_header_timeout           60;
  send_timeout                    60;
  lingering_time                  30;
  lingering_timeout                5;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout         60;
  fastcgi_send_timeout           300;
  fastcgi_read_timeout           300;

 ## Open File Performance
  open_file_cache max=8000 inactive=30s;
  open_file_cache_valid          60s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses         3;
  open_file_cache_errors          on;

 ## FastCGI Caching
  fastcgi_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/speed
                     levels=2:2:2
                     keys_zone=speed:10m
                     inactive=15m
                     max_size=3g;

 ## General Options
  ignore_invalid_headers          on;
  limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=gulag:10m;
  recursive_error_pages           on;
  reset_timedout_connection       on;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
  server_tokens                  off;
  fastcgi_hide_header         'Link';
  fastcgi_hide_header  'X-Generator';
  fastcgi_hide_header 'X-Powered-By';
  fastcgi_hide_header 'X-Drupal-Cache';

 ## TCP options moved to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

 ## SSL performance
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout            10m;

 ## GeoIP support
  geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

 ## Compression
  gzip_buffers      16 8k;
  gzip_comp_level   5;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_min_length   10;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      any;
  add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
  gzip_static       on;
  upload_progress uploads 1m;

 ## Log Format
  log_format        main '"$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for" $host [$time_local] '
                         '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                         '$request_length $bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                         '"$http_user_agent" $request_time "$gzip_ratio"';

  client_body_temp_path  /var/lib/nginx/body 1 2;
  access_log             /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

# Extra configuration from modules:
#######################################################
###  nginx default maps
#######################################################

###
### Support separate Boost and Speed Booster caches for various mobile devices.
###
map $http_user_agent $device {
  default                                                                normal;
  ~*Nokia|BlackBerry.+MIDP|240x|320x|Palm|NetFront|Symbian|SonyEricsson  mobile-other;
  ~*iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry.+AppleWebKit                          mobile-smart;
  ~*iPad|Tablet                                                          mobile-tablet;
}

###
### Set a cache_uid variable for authenticated users (by @brianmercer and @perusio, fixed by @omega8cc).
###
map $http_cookie $cache_uid {
  default  '';
  ~SESS[[:alnum:]]+=(?<session_id>[[:graph:]]+)  $session_id;
}

###
### Live switch of $key_uri for Speed Booster cache depending on $args.
###
map $request_uri $key_uri {
  default                                                                            $request_uri;
  ~(?<no_args_uri>[[:graph:]]+)\?(.*)(utm_|__utm|_campaign|gclid|source=|adv=|req=)  $no_args_uri;
}

###
### Set cache expiration depending on the Drupal core version.
###
map $sent_http_x_purge_level $will_expire_in {
  default   on-demand;
  ~*5|none  5m;
}

###
### Deny crawlers.
###
map $http_user_agent $is_crawler {
  default  '';
  ~*HTTrack|BrokenLinkCheck|2009042316.*Firefox.*3\.0\.10|MJ12|HTMLParser|libwww|PECL|Automatic|Click|SiteBot|BuzzTrack|Sistrix|Offline|Screaming|Nutch|Mireo|SWEB|Morfeus|GSLFbot  is_crawler;
}

###
### Deny all known bots on some URIs.
###
map $http_user_agent $is_bot {
  default  '';
  ~*crawl|goog|yahoo|yandex|spider|bot|tracker|click|parser  is_bot;
}

###
### Deny almost all crawlers under high load.
###
map $http_user_agent $deny_on_high_load {
  default  '';
  ~*crawl|goog|yahoo|yandex|baidu|bing|spider|tracker|click|parser  deny_on_high_load;
}

###
### Deny listed requests for security reasons.
###
map $args $is_denied {
  default  '';
  ~*delete.+from|insert.+into|select.+from|union.+select|onload|\.php.+src|system\(.+|document\.cookie|\;|\.\.  is_denied;
}

#######################################################
###  nginx default server
#######################################################

server {
  limit_conn   gulag 32; # like mod_evasive - this allows max 32 simultaneous connections from one IP address
  listen       *:80;
  server_name  _;
  location / {
     root   /var/www/nginx-default;
     index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}

#######################################################
###  nginx virtual domains
#######################################################

# virtual hosts
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/pre.d/*;
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/platform.d/*;
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/vhost.d/*;
include /var/aegir/config/server_master/nginx/post.d/*;
```

In the included directories at the end are some servers defined which listen to specific subdomains (set up by aegir). I think these don't affect us here.

UPDATE 2:

Thanks davismwfl and Melvyn for you input. Now it's getting interesting:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

When I create a server which should only redirect http://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com requests get redirected to https://.. and then stuck in a redirect loop.

If I understand this right for some reason the server which shall listen to port 80 also listens to https requests and tries *again* to redirect requests.

Do you guy know why?

Any ideas what the problem might be or why it does what it does?

Thanks a lot, Martin

Comment: This looks ok. So is this all of your config or is a default sever defined somewhere?

Comment: I added another config file which is used, maybe you see something that explains the behavior. I don't :)

Answer (score 6):

So, I do this the reverse way.  I literally had this issue the other day.  One thing is the order was found to be important, and I really should have changed the "rewrite" rules to "return 301 ..." but I got lazy and didn't do that yet as I was in a bit of a hurry.

Here is a snippet of my config

```
#
# Rewrite any http requests for domain.com to https.
#
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name domain.com;
   return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
#
# Rewrite any http requests for www.domain.com to domain.com
# using SSL
#
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.domain.com;
   rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain.com/$1 permanent;
}

#
# The domain.com website
#
server {
   listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/[crt];
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/[key];
    ... Bunches of more stuff goes here. 
}

#
# Rewrite any https requests for www.domain.com to domain.com
# Note that this must be after the domain.com declaration.
#
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name www.domain.com;
   rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: why is order important?  just throw the default_server flag on the primary server

Comment: @Chris what happens if he's hosting multiple domains (virtual hosts)?

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why order would be important here, but for me putting the `listen 443; server_name www.domain.com;` server block above the main config was blocking requests to the non-www domain. Doesn't make any sense since it seems like that block should not match the request, but I'm just happy that this solution is working.

Answer (score 2):

The most nice way that I found looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  examle.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/[crt];
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/[key];
    ... 
}
```

In this way you can use `$server_name` instead of hardcoded values.