# Redirect http to https with nginx instead of using django-sslify?

Tags: python, django, redirect, ssl, nginx

I tried to use django-sslify and django-secure to redirect all http requests to https, but i just can't get it to work. Is it a valid solution to redirect them with nginx instead, like it is shown here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947646/nginx-redirect-http-to-https-whats-wrong-here)
Or, maybe someone could explain, what is wrong with my config right now:
Before i added "proxy_set_header Host $host;" to the second server block it redirected nicely, but forms wouldn't work, because the csrf protection threw referrer errors.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;

location /static {
    alias /home/adrian/sites/www.domain.com/static;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/www.domain.com.socket;
}
}
server {
    listen 200.200.200.200:443;
    server_name domain.com;

 location /static {
    alias /home/adrian/sites/www.domain.com/static;
}

location / {

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/www.domain.com.de.socket;
}

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.de.key;

   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, never mind. Django-sslify just didn't work for some reason and so i retried django-secure with

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

set and it did work like a charm. But i would really like to hear, if it would be better or more efficient to redirect with nginx and i will accept that answer. Thanks.