# nginx redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I'm setting up an e-commerce domain on a nginx server which should fulfill the following conditions:

- https://www.domain.com is the only URL format visitors should use to access the store
- https://domain.com
- http://www.domain.com
- http://domain.com ALL three must redirect to https://www.domain.com

With the configuration shown below, [based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947646/nginx-redirect-http-to-https-whats-wrong-here) pursuing the opposite case, i.e. force all traffic to https://domain.com with no www, I get the following results:

- http://www.domain.com redirects to https://www.domain.com **[GOOD]**
- http://domain.com redirects to https://www.domain.com **[GOOD]**
- https://domain.com returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED **[BAD]**

How can I redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com? Check my current config:

```
#
# Rewrite any http requests for DOMAIN.com to www.DOMAIN.com using SSL
#
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name DOMAIN.com;
    return 301 https://www.DOMAIN.com$request_uri;
}

#
# Rewrite any http requests for www.DOMAIN.com to https
#
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.DOMAIN.com;
    return 301 https://www.DOMAIN.com$request_uri;
}

#
# The DOMAIN.com website
#
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    server_name DOMAIN.com;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www_DOMAIN_com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www_DOMAIN_com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    if ($host = DOMAIN.com) {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.DOMAIN.com:443$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location @handler {
            rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ssl directives are missing on the 443 DOMAIN.com block. You must of course have a valid certificate for DOMAIN.com

Comment: That's the point, we have a certificate for www.DOMAIN.com only and that's the reason we want a forced redirect from secure DOMAIN.com to www.DOMAIN.com. I'm wondering if such redirect is possible at the webserver level, or if we need to look higher, say at the DNS config.

Comment: You can't redirect an https on a server without a certificate. DNS doesn't help. You can get a free certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Comment: Turns out the certificate works for DOMAIN.com and www.DOMAIN.com, and the issue was in the DNS configuration (an @ record conflicting with the intended redirection). I will update my question with the working nginx conf if that helps anyone stumbling upon this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

The above configuration works, the issue was actually in the DNS settings.