# NGINX redirect http to https

Tags: nginx

Hi I would like to redirect all pages when a user try to access it from http to https. I already setup the ssl but if the url just typed in the http it doesn't redirect them to https. I need to redirect them to https for all pages. How do I achieve this?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.website.local;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    root /var/www/website/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx redirect Http to Https - what's wrong here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947646/nginx-redirect-http-to-https-whats-wrong-here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate config for `http 80` to redirect to `https 443`.

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             *.website.local;

    return          301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a separate config if you don't want one, you can add `if ($scheme != "https") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }` to your existing server config.

Comment: What config if server_name is IP(not domain name)?